Some problem in tensorflow_hub, tensorflow_text, and transformers when working on BERT and RoBerta
I am working on RoBerta, but I am unable to import TFAutoModel from transformers. Initially it was possible but from a few weeks there is some problem in tensorflow_text and transformers. Please help.
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer, TFRobertaModel
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
model = TFRobertaModel.from_pretrained("roberta-base")
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.roberta.modeling_tf_roberta because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.internal' has no attribute 'register_load_context_function'
